# Pinia warning "Insepctor pinia not found"

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Started using Pinia recently with Vue3 using the Setup Store syntax. Everything seems to be working fine but I have this warning in the console. `Inspector pinia not found` Is this anything to be worried about, what's going on? I have the Vue devtools installed, I get the feeling it is something about that, but Pinia works fine in the devtools as well.

[image]

Comment: Also getting this, it used to work no problems. I can no longer see pinia in the dev tools anymore. Did you solve this?

Comment: I'm also getting this. My vue-devtools are currently working.

Comment: Sorry for delay, unfortunately I never got this resolved. I'm working on a chrome extension which the vue devtools doesn't work with anyway so unclear whether it is truly an issue or not. I've not experienced any issues using Pinia though.